# How to use optional values in Laravel routes?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('users/search/{type?}/{value}', 'Site\UserController@search');
```

The main idea is to simplify the search:

if type exists (name, surname, email and etc.) search only by that field.
if not - search everywhere.

But when I do:

```
http://example.com/users/search/sdgfdfxg
```

Laravel throws

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

With

`http://example.com/users/search/name/sdgfdfxg`

or

`http://example.com/users/search/surname/sdgfdfxg`

everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yust define 2 routes:

```
Route::get('users/search/{type}/{value}',function($type,$value){
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('Site\UserController');
    $controller->callAction($app, $app['router'], 'search', $parameters = array($type,$value));
});
Route::get('users/search/{value}',function($value){
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make('Site\UserController');
    $controller->callAction($app, $app['router'], 'search', $parameters = array(null,$value));
});
```

But still the easiest option is to change the order of defining you're parameters. Set the optional option to the end of the url:

```
Route::get('users/search/{value}/{type?}','Site\UserController@search');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could register 2 routes. One with 'type' and one without to handle both cases.

```
Route::get('users/search/{type}/{value}', 'Site\UserController@searchByType');
Route::get('users/search/{value}', 'Site\UserController@search');
```